# Не приходят данные json

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jquery-mobile, android-webview

На локальном сервере, на пк все выводит,но как только это делаю на смартфоне `Request Failed:error`,в чем ошибка?

```
 $('#test').on('tap', function(event) {
                var jqxhr = $.getJSON("one.json", function(data) {
                    console.log("success");
                    alert(data.name + " " + data.one);
                    $("#json").html(data.name + " " + data.one);
                }).done(function() {
                    console.log("second success");
                    $("#d1").html("second success");
                }).fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
                    var err = textStatus + ', ' + error;
                    console.log("Request Failed: " + err);
                    $("#d2").html("Request Failed: " + err);
                }).always(function() {
                    console.log("complete");
                    $("#d3").html("complete");
                });
            });
```

Comment: Если у вас android, вы можете отлаживать код на desktop chmore подключи телефон по usb. Ищите chrome mobile debugger. Это практичный вариант, на будущее. А так можно и alert`ом узнать. Если err - это объект, то получить ключи с помощью Object.keys(err) и далее двигаться.

Comment: Вот сейчас протестировал на htc работает,на sumsung нет

Comment: @zkolya может у вас на samsun браузер совсем старый?

Comment: Там он обернут в `webview`  на sumsung android 4.2.1,а на htc, работает и там 4.0.3

Answer (score 1):

Вот решение

```
if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN){
webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
}
```